# How to display several divs on area and fill it rationally

Tags: html, css

I have 4 divs, and want that the last div was under first div. But for some reason it goes more above that needed. as I know it is because of float: left and because of third div.

[image]

Is it possible to move it above?

Currently this code I use:

```
<div id="id1"></div>
<div id="id2"></div>
<div id="id3"></div>
<div id="id4"></div>
```

Each div has different sizes and each of them have `float: left;`

Comment: If the content is static you can use CSS to pull up the last div, otherwise you'll need JavaScript to fix it.

Comment: the content is dynamic

Comment: how the javascript may help for this? The sizes of each div can be different every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple answer, you cant (in vanilla CSS/HTML)

(sorry)

### However..

There are relatively capable libraries out there which allow you to accomplish this with ease, such as  [**Masonry**](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [**Isotope**](http://isotope.metafizzy.co). The alternative being to code your own solution in Javascript.